# Imputation with mice alters original values in variables without NAs - R

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am doing multiple imputation with mice but I am surprised to see that original values in variables that did not have NAs are altered and distorted.

For a reproducible example see below.  I will use mtcars (base R) and embed in it randomly NAs in 2 columns -- disp and hp.  I will mark the position of these NAs.  Then I will impute the missing values and compare them with the original.  Finally I will plot the results in a scatterplot : original values vs. imputed values.  I would expect the original values to be in line with imputed values for the columns that did not have NAs since no imputation should have taken there place.  But this is not the case. The code and the plots are the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(mice)
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
dim(mtcars)
# 32 11
mtcars_original <- copy(mtcars)
mtcars[as.numeric(sample(row.names(mtcars), 7)), ]$hp <- NA
mtcars[as.numeric(sample(row.names(mtcars), 7)), ]$disp <- NA
mtcars[, ":="(hp_NA = ifelse(is.na(hp), 1, 0) , disp_NA = ifelse(is.na(disp), 1, 0))]
mtcars_imputed <- complete(mice(mtcars))
mtcars_imputed$disp_original <- mtcars_original$disp
mtcars_imputed$hp_original <- mtcars_original$hp

ggplot(mtcars_imputed, aes(x = disp_original, y= disp, color = as.factor(disp_NA))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + ggtitle("Match between original and imputed values \n disp") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 2) + theme_economist()

ggplot(mtcars_imputed, aes(x = hp_original, y= hp, color = as.factor(hp_NA))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + ggtitle("Match between original and imputed values \n hp") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = "red", alpha = 0.3, size = 2) + theme_economist()
```

[image]

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please put the necessary `library` calls at the top of your code.

Comment: The problem isn't `mice` but your use of `data.table`. Specifically, the two lines that insert `NA` in the data also reorder the rows of the data. Consequently, when you add the "original" values later on, you're adding them in a different order. The observed values aren't changed, only the plot is misleading.

Comment: Add a line saying `mtcars$row <- 1:32` before you start altering `mtcars` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you.  But why the rows are reordered?